# PHP Sending huge amount of emails with Swiftmailer + Sendgrid

Tags: php, swiftmailer, sendgrid

I'm currently sending emails from my site using Sendgrid SMTP service with SwiftMailer (over 1k per day). Now I want to start sending a newsletter to 100k addresses once a week.

1. Should I limit the batch to a certain number of addresses? Lets say, instead of sending 100k at once, only 10k.
2. Should I loop the addresses and send each email separately or better set the addresses as BCC?

Comment: I think a server can handle sending a couple of thousands of e-mails easily. My biggest worry would be that the internet and mail providers blacklist you for being a spam sender and block every single e-mail originating from you. Did you look into that already?

Comment: Yes, that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Increasing the batch size from 1K to 100K is not a good idea over the network. Sweet spot is to have 1000 recipients max to have the best performance.
But, there are other tools to optimise the performance.

Are you sending only email id or you have other attributes like Name, City etc ?